# how to get Hyperlink in PHP for echo statements

Tags: php, html, image

I have piece of php code which I want to put as a link.

```
      echo"<img border='1' src='$images[$i]' width='350' height='250'>";
```

This is what I came up with

```
       <a href = "something"> above statement <a>
```

but this gives me error.

Comment: The last tag should be `</a>`.

Comment: Please, please, **please**, when you get an error, indicate what it is. "this gives me error" is totally useless information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo "<a href = 'something'><img border='1' src='".$images[$i]."' width='350' height='250'></a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo"<a href=\"something\"><img border='1' src='$images[$i]' width='350' height='250'></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"
    <a href='...'>
       <img border='1' src='{$images[$i]}' width='350' height='250'>
    </a>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "<a href="url" > <img border='1' src='".$images[$i]."' width='350' height='250'> </a>";
```

OR

```
    <a href="url" > <?php echo "<img border='1' src='".$images[$i]."' width='350' height='250'>"; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [concatenate dot operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in this way:

```
<?php
echo '<img border="1" width="350" height="250" src="'.$images[$i].'"'>;
?>
```